# Suddenly lost my Firebase Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've done my project for a year. Now my Firebase Firestore suddenly looks like this:
[image]

Furthermore, when clicking the `Create database` button. I can't select any region like the picture below:[image]

Is that a bug?

Comment: you can view in [Firestore audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#viewing_logs) that who deleted and when this happen

Answer (score 0):

Turn out I had an issue with Google Cloud Billing. Resolved it and things back to normal